# Python Discord Bot - Command Concurrency

Tags: python, concurrency, discord, discord.py

I'm currently implementing a Discord Bot for my server and I'm running into a little concurrency issue.

**First, the objective:**

> After a particular command is triggered on Discord the bot is supposed to send a message for "voting purposes". It sends the message, adds a like and dislike reaction and waits for three other likes (or stops after 15 seconds). After that it replies with a reaction to the original message (the command trigger).

**The problem:**

> If I run this command twice (or more), while they do both wait for reactions, if I like one of them it also adds the "like count" to the second one.

I presumed that *discord.py-rewrite* would run multiple executions of the same command in parallel without interacting with one another. Is this presumption incorrect? Or does the problem lie in this particular piece of code?

I've read around *Stackoverflow* that *asyncio* isn't thread-safe, but I've also read that it is.

Is there way around this? How could I go about solving this problem?

Thank you in advance.

**PS:** *All the imports are in place and everything is working if the command is executed only once at a time*

````py
@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 2, commands.BucketType.guild)
async def flames(ctx, *, msg):
    msg = await ctx.send(f'blah? (15sec to vote)\n```{msg}```')
    await msg.add_reaction('')
    await msg.add_reaction('')
    reaction = None
    try:
        while reaction == None or \
        (str(reaction.emoji) != '' and reaction.count <= 3):
            reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=15.0)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await msg.delete()
        await sendTempMsg(ctx, 3, f'{ctx.message.author.mention} denied.')
        await ctx.message.add_reaction('')
    else:
        await msg.delete()
        await sendTempMsg(ctx, 3, f'{ctx.message.author.mention} approved!')
        await ctx.message.add_reaction('')

async def sendTempMsg(ctx, time, msg):
    tempMsg = await ctx.send(msg)
    await asyncio.sleep(time)
    await tempMsg.delete()
````

Comment: You are waiting for a `reaction_add` event, but you're not filtering which message was reacted to. `msg.id == reaction.message.id`. I think you also have a problem with the timeout in that the line `reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=15.0)` could run multiple times for multiple loop iterations, so it could wait more than 15 seconds total.

Comment: asyncio is not thread safe, but you're not using thread here. multiple calls to the command are being interleaved, because `await` pauses execution until the thing being waited on is finished and lets something else run (another call to the command in this case). They're  affecting each other because of the lack of filtering which message you're watching reactions on as I mentioned previously.